# jqGrid stopped loading json data on Archlinux

Tags: linux, jqgrid

It was working fine yesterday. Now the grid is empty. (i did an update at night.) But if i try from windows xp machine, both IE and FF4 load grid just fine. Everything works.

But from linux (archlinux 64 bit), neither FF4 nor Chromium load data. The grid is empty.

Obviously the problem is not in my code. It's working fine. Something happened to FF (and Chromium ?)

Does anyone else have this problem ?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){var lastsel,tbl=$("#tblPrintSets");
   tbl.jqGrid({url:"http://192.168.1.147:3000/json/print-sets",
               editurl:"http://192.168.1.147:3000/print-sets/post",
               datatype:"json",height:400,
               jsonReader:{repeatitems:false,id:"set_id"},
               colNames:["ID","Seq #","Set name","File Name","Group Level","Exclude Attachments"],
               colModel:[{name:'set_id',sortable:false,editable:false,width:40},
                         {name:'seq_no',sortable:false,editable:true,width:50,editoptions:{size:4},editrules:{required:true,number:true}},
                         {name:'set_name',sortable:false,editable:true,width:200,editoptions:{size:25},editrules:{required:true}},
                      {name:'file_name',sortable:false,editable:true,width:200,editoptions:{size:25},editrules:{required:true}},
                    {name:'group_level',sortable:false,editable:true,width:100,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Order;2:Service List;3:Location"}},
              {name:'exclude_attachments',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Yes;0:No",defaultValue:"No"}}],
            onSelectRow:function(id){if(id&&id!==lastsel){tbl.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                    tbl.jqGrid('editRow',id,true);lastsel=id}}});

     $("#btnNewSet").click(function(){tbl.jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:200,closeAfterAdd:true,recreateForm:true})})})
```

and here's the json data:

```
{"rows":[{"exclude_attachments":"No","file_name":"inhouse","group_level":"Location","seq_no":"1","set_id":"1","set_name":"In House"},
     {"exclude_attachments":"No","file_name":"client","group_level":"Order","seq_no":"2","set_id":"2","set_name":"Client Set"},
       {"exclude_attachments":"No","file_name":"oc","group_level":"Service List","seq_no":"3","set_id":"3","set_name":"O.C. Set"},
       {"exclude_attachments":"No","file_name":"service","group_level":"Service List","seq_no":"4","set_id":"4","set_name":"Service List Set"}]}
```

jqgrid version: 4.0

jquery: 1.5.2

jquery-ui: 1.8.11

EDIT: Thanks to help from Oleg, the problem is solved. It turned out i was using absolute urls for json data. And with absolute urls it must match the url you are accessing the web site. I was accessing the web site with "localhost" url on the host machine. That's why it did not work.

Comment: You should post the JavaScript code which defines the jqGrid, test JSON data and information which versions of jqGrid, jQuery and jQuery UI you use.

Comment: I would, if my code was broken. But it is not. It works on windows machine, plus it was working yesterday, and i did not change it since then. But i did update last night of linux packages, i just do not remember what the heck was updated. Anyway, i'll post the code, i just know there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/VagifVerdi.htm) the jqGrid woks in general.

I suppose that your main problem exist because of the usage `http://192.168.1.147:3000` prefix in the url. I suppose that either IP address or the port number are changed now or the web site run on the other web server. Ajax has an important restriction known under the name [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can not get data from the server having another IP as the current web server. Even the port number should be the same. So you should never use absolute paths for the `url` and change it to url:"/json/print-sets" and `editurl:"/print-sets/post"` for example.

One more remark. Your JSON data has no id information. Accidentally the 'set_id' values from the input data is 1,2,3. If jqGrid find no information about ids in the JSON input it use also 1,2,3... So you have no problem with the editing of the data. If some column (like 'set_id') contain unique id you should include `key:true` in the corresponding column definition.

Comment: The thing is, it works on windows machine, both on IE and FF4. And it DID perfectly work on linux machine as well (until i updated it). So i am sure the absolute urls are not a problem. But i'll try your suggestion anyway. I'll let you know if it helps. As for id for JSON, my JSOnReader has id: "set_id". But i'll put key: true too. Won't hurt.

Comment: @Vagif Verdi: You are right with `id: "set_id"` in the `jsonReader`. I overlooked this. If you use `key:true` it do the same. I prefer the way with `key:true` because it is the part of data model amd is independent of input format (`jsonReader`, `xmlReader`). Let me know what was the problem in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg! You were spot on. The problem was the url. I was using "localhost" url, instead of full url. That's why it worked on other pc, because there i was using the full url. I agree btw about the key being defined in the model. Also i noticed that labels can be placed there too. So i wonder if it is better to get rid of colNames option.

Comment: @Vagif Verdi: You are welcome! What do you mean under "to get rid of colNames option"?

Comment: remove  colNames:["ID","Seq #","Set name"], and put "label" option in colModel. Which way is preferable ?

Comment: @Vagif Verdi: OK, clear! It gives the same results. It is mostly the question of the taste. I prefer to use `label` property in the `colModel` mostly if there are many column where `name` property is the same as in the `colNames` (or `label`). In the case you don't need define `label` for the column. In general the usage of `colNames` reduce a little the size of JavaScript code, so one use the way in the most cases.